# php Send mail not working in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a contact form where the user inputs his name, designation, message etc and is validated using a javascript file called **screen.js**.
This is my code in the contact form in html view.

```
<div class="contact_us">
    <form id="contactform" action="#" method="post">
        <div class="formpart">
            <label for="contact_name">Name</label>
            <p><input type="text" name="name" id="contact_name" value="" class="requiredfield"/></p>
        </div>  
        <div class="formpart formpart1">
            <label for="contact_designation">Designation</label>
            <p><input type="text" name="designation" id="contact_designation" value=""/></p>
        </div>  
        <div class="formpart">
            <label for="contact_companyname">Company Name</label>
            <p><input type="text" name="companyname" id="contact_companyname" value="" class="requiredfield"/></p>
        </div>  
        <div class="formpart formpart1">
            <label for="contact_email">Email Address</label>
            <p><input type="text" name="email" id="contact_email" value="" class="requiredfield"/></p>
        </div>  
        <div class="formpart">
            <label for="contact_phone">Contact No.</label>
            <p><input type="text" name="phone" id="contact_phone" value=""/></p>
        </div>
        <div class="formpart">
            <label for="contact_message">Message</label>
            <p><textarea name="message" id="contact_message" class="requiredfield"></textarea></p>
        </div>          
        <div class="formpart">
            <button type="submit" name="send" class="sendmessage">Send</button>
        </div>
        <div class="formpart">
            <span class="errormessage">Error! Please correct marked fields.</span>
            <span class="successmessage">Email send successfully!</span>
            <span class="sendingmessage">Sending...</span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

and the javascript file **screen.js** contains

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 


    /* Contact Form */
    if(jQuery('#contactform').length != 0){
        addForm('#contactform');
    }

    /* Newsletter Subscription */
    if(jQuery('#newsletterform').length != 0){
        addForm('#newsletterform');
    }

});

/* Contact Form */
function addForm(formtype) {

    var formid = jQuery(formtype);
    var emailsend = false;

    formid.find("button[name=send]").click(sendemail);

    function validator() {

        var emailcheck = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
        var othercheck = /.{4}/;
        var noerror = true;

        formid.find(".requiredfield").each(function () {

            var fieldname = jQuery(this).attr('name');
            var value = jQuery(this).val();

            if(fieldname == "email"){
                if (!emailcheck.test(value)) {
                    jQuery(this).addClass("formerror");
                    noerror = false;
                } else {
                    jQuery(this).removeClass("formerror");
                }   
            }else{
                if (!othercheck.test(value)) {
                    jQuery(this).addClass("formerror");
                    noerror = false;
                } else {
                    jQuery(this).removeClass("formerror");
                }   
            }
        })

        if(!noerror){
            formid.find(".errormessage").fadeIn();
        }

        return noerror;
    }

    function resetform() {
        formid.find("input").each(function () {
            jQuery(this).val("");   
        })
        formid.find("textarea").val("");
        emailsend = false;
    }

    function sendemail() {
        formid.find(".successmessage").hide();
        var phpfile = "";
        if(formtype=="#contactform"){
            phpfile = "../php/contact.php";
        }else if(formtype=="#newsletterform"){
            phpfile = "php/signup.php";
        }else{
            phpfile = "";
        }
        if (validator()) {
            if(!emailsend){
                emailsend = true;
                formid.find(".errormessage").hide();
                formid.find(".sendingmessage").show();
                jQuery.post(phpfile, formid.serialize(), function() {
                    formid.find(".sendingmessage").hide();
                    formid.find(".successmessage").fadeIn();
                    resetform();
                });
            }
        } 
        return false
    }
}
```

and my php file contact.php

```
<?php

$to = "developer@vakilspremedia.com"; /* Enter your email adress here */

$name = trim($_POST['name']);
$designation = trim($_POST['designation']);
$companyname = trim($_POST['companyname']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$phone = trim($_POST['phone']);
$message = str_replace(chr(10), "<br>", $_POST['message']);

$body = "<html><head><title>Contact Form Email</title></head><body><br>";
$body .= "Name: <b>" . $name . "</b><br>";
$body .= "Designation: <b>" . $designation . "</b><br>";
$body .= "Company Name: <b>" . $companyname . "</b><br>";
$body .= "Email: <b>" . $email . "</b><br>";
$body .= "Phone: <b>" . $phone . "</b><br><br>";
$body .= "Message:<br><hr><br><b>" . $message . "</b><br>";
$body .= "<br></body></html>";

$subject = 'Contact Form Email from ' . $name;
$header = "From: $to\n" . "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";

mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);

?>
```

The validation works perfect but when I enter values in all field it shows **sending...** as the message and doesn't show Email successfully sent at all even after hours and hours of waiting. It seems it does nothing after I click on send button.

Comment: and where is your PHP logic behind this form??

Comment: @jogesh_p I have put the code, kindly see the edit

Comment: are you getting any kind of error?? or have you debugged the input is properly going to your PHP file??

Comment: @jogesh_p it doesn't show any error. yes it shows error if i miss entering any mandatory field, it shows error then. As I mentioned in my question validation is working fine, only thing it does when i click on send button is it shows **sending...**

Comment: @jogesh_p it doesn't reach my php file.

Comment: you have to make some extension for this, or have to use some in-build extensions, because am not sure but i think in wordpress you don't call directly to any php file.

Comment: PHP's `mail()` function sucks. I recommend avoiding it. Use a decent class like [phpMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/) instead -- you'll save yourself a lot of effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify ur js for this code make sure phpfile var have url path or put contact.php in same directory

jQuery.post('contact.php', formid.serialize(), function() {

```
                console.log('success');
                formid.find(".sendingmessage").hide();
                formid.find(".successmessage").fadeIn();
                resetform();
```

});

Comment: I gave a complete path of where my contact.php and signup.php was located. And it worked . Thanks..